# org-agenda: display entire todo(s) matching a certain tag (not just headlines)

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When clicking on a tag in org-mode `(org-tags-view)`, the org-agenda buffer displays each todo with just the headings.  Is there an option to display the *entire entry* for each todo that matches the tag search?

Specifically, I want to include the deadlines and scheduled dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** (December 12, 2013):  First working draft.

**EDIT** (January 6, 2014):  See this related thread for an example of matching any element from the stars at the beginning through to multi-line notes at the end of the task -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942168/how-to-match-parse-the-notes-at-the-end-of-a-task-in-org-mode

```
(defalias 'org-tags-view 'tag)

(defun tag (&optional todo-only match)
  "Show all headlines (plus deadlines) for all `org-agenda-files' matching a TAGS criterion.
The prefix arg TODO-ONLY limits the search to TODO entries."
  (interactive "P")
  (if org-agenda-overriding-arguments
      (setq todo-only (car org-agenda-overriding-arguments)
      match (nth 1 org-agenda-overriding-arguments)))
  (let* (
      (org-tags-match-list-sublevels org-tags-match-list-sublevels)
      (completion-ignore-case t)
       rtn
       rtnall
       files
       file
       pos
       matcher
       buffer)
    (when (and (stringp match) (not (string-match "\\S-" match)))
      (setq match nil))
    (setq matcher (org-make-tags-matcher match)
    match (car matcher) matcher (cdr matcher))
    (catch 'exit
      (if org-agenda-sticky
    (setq org-agenda-buffer-name
    (if (stringp match)
        (format "*Org Agenda(%s:%s)*"
          (or org-keys (or (and todo-only "M") "m")) match)
      (format "*Org Agenda(%s)*" (or (and todo-only "M") "m")))))
      (org-agenda-prepare (concat "TAGS " match))
      (org-compile-prefix-format 'tags)
      (org-set-sorting-strategy 'tags)
      (setq org-agenda-query-string match)
      (setq org-agenda-redo-command
            (list 'org-tags-view `(quote ,todo-only)
            (list 'if 'current-prefix-arg nil `(quote ,org-agenda-query-string))))
      (setq files (org-agenda-files nil 'ifmode)
      rtnall nil)
      (while (setq file (pop files))
  (catch 'nextfile
    (org-check-agenda-file file)
    (setq buffer (if (file-exists-p file)
         (org-get-agenda-file-buffer file)
       (error "No such file %s" file)))
    (if (not buffer)
        (setq rtn (list
       (format "ORG-AGENDA-ERROR: No such org-file %s" file))
        rtnall (append rtnall rtn))
      (with-current-buffer buffer
        (unless (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
    (error "Agenda file %s is not in `org-mode'" file))
        (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (if org-agenda-restrict
          (narrow-to-region org-agenda-restrict-begin
          org-agenda-restrict-end)
        (widen))
      (setq rtn (lawlist-scan-tags 'agenda matcher todo-only))
      (setq rtnall (append rtnall rtn))))))))
      (if org-agenda-overriding-header
    (insert (org-add-props (copy-sequence org-agenda-overriding-header)
          nil 'face 'org-agenda-structure) "\n")
  (insert "TAGS: " match "\n") )
  (org-agenda-mark-header-line (point-min))
  (when rtnall
    (insert (org-agenda-finalize-entries rtnall) "\n"))
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (or org-agenda-multi (org-agenda-fit-window-to-buffer))
  (org-agenda-finalize)
  (setq buffer-read-only t)
  (font-lock-mode 1))))

(defun lawlist-scan-tags (action matcher todo-only &optional start-level)
  (require 'org-agenda)
  (let* ((re (concat "^"
         (if start-level
       (concat "\\*\\{" (number-to-string start-level) "\\} ")
           org-outline-regexp)
         " *\\(\\<\\("
         (mapconcat 'regexp-quote org-todo-keywords-1 "\\|")
         (org-re "\\)\\>\\)? *\\(.*?\\)\\(:[[:alnum:]_@#%:]+:\\)?[ \t]*$") ))
   (props (list 'face 'default
          'done-face 'org-agenda-done
          'undone-face 'default
          'mouse-face 'highlight
          'org-not-done-regexp org-not-done-regexp
          'org-todo-regexp org-todo-regexp
          'org-complex-heading-regexp org-complex-heading-regexp
          'help-echo
          (format "mouse-2 or RET jump to org file %s"
            (abbreviate-file-name
             (or (buffer-file-name (buffer-base-buffer))
           (buffer-name (buffer-base-buffer)))))))
   (case-fold-search nil)
   (org-map-continue-from nil)
         lspos tags tags-list
   (tags-alist (list (cons 0 org-file-tags)))
   (llast 0) rtn rtn1 level category i txt
   todo marker entry priority)
    (when (not (or (member action '(agenda sparse-tree)) (functionp action)))
      (setq action (list 'lambda nil action)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (when (eq action 'sparse-tree)
  (org-overview)
  (org-remove-occur-highlights))
      (while (re-search-forward re nil t)
  (setq org-map-continue-from nil)
  (catch :skip
    (setq todo (if (match-end 1) (org-match-string-no-properties 2))
    tags (if (match-end 4) (org-match-string-no-properties 4)))
    (goto-char (setq lspos (match-beginning 0)))
    (setq level (org-reduced-level (funcall outline-level))
    category (org-get-category))
    (setq i llast llast level)
    (while (>= i level)
      (when (setq entry (assoc i tags-alist))
        (setq tags-alist (delete entry tags-alist)))
      (setq i (1- i)))
    (when tags
      (setq tags (org-split-string tags ":")
      tags-alist
      (cons (cons level tags) tags-alist)))
    (setq tags-list
    (if org-use-tag-inheritance
        (apply 'append (mapcar 'cdr (reverse tags-alist)))
      tags)
    org-scanner-tags tags-list)
    (when org-use-tag-inheritance
      (setcdr (car tags-alist)
        (mapcar (lambda (x)
            (setq x (copy-sequence x))
            (org-add-prop-inherited x))
          (cdar tags-alist))))
    (when (and tags org-use-tag-inheritance
         (or (not (eq t org-use-tag-inheritance))
       org-tags-exclude-from-inheritance))
      (setcdr (car tags-alist)
        (org-remove-uninherited-tags (cdar tags-alist))))
    (when (and
     (and (or (not todo-only) (member todo org-not-done-keywords))
          (let ((case-fold-search t) (org-trust-scanner-tags t))
      (eval matcher)))
     (progn
       (unless (eq action 'sparse-tree) (org-agenda-skip))
       t)
     (or (not todo-only)
         (and (member todo org-not-done-keywords)
        (or (not org-agenda-tags-todo-honor-ignore-options)
            (not (org-agenda-check-for-timestamp-as-reason-to-ignore-todo-item))))))
      (cond
       ((eq action 'sparse-tree)
        (and org-highlight-sparse-tree-matches
       (org-get-heading) (match-end 0)
       (org-highlight-new-match
        (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)))
        (org-show-context 'tags-tree))
       ((eq action 'agenda)
        (setq txt (lawlist-org-get-heading))
        (goto-char lspos)
        (setq marker (org-agenda-new-marker))
        (org-add-props txt props
    'org-marker marker 'org-hd-marker marker 'org-category category
    'todo-state todo
    'priority priority 'type "tagsmatch")
        (push txt rtn))
       ((functionp action)
        (setq org-map-continue-from nil)
        (save-excursion
    (setq rtn1 (funcall action))
    (push rtn1 rtn)))
       (t (error "Invalid action")))
      (unless org-tags-match-list-sublevels
        (org-end-of-subtree t)
        (backward-char 1))))
  (if org-map-continue-from
      (goto-char org-map-continue-from)
    (and (= (point) lspos) (end-of-line 1)))))
    (when (and (eq action 'sparse-tree)
         (not org-sparse-tree-open-archived-trees))
      (org-hide-archived-subtrees (point-min) (point-max)))
    (nreverse rtn)))

(defun lawlist-org-get-heading (&optional no-tags no-todo)
  "Return the heading of the current entry, without the stars.
When NO-TAGS is non-nil, don't include tags.
When NO-TODO is non-nil, don't include TODO keywords."
  (save-excursion
    (org-back-to-heading t)
    (cond
     ((and no-tags no-todo)
      (looking-at org-complex-heading-regexp)
      (match-string 4))
     (no-tags
      (looking-at (concat org-outline-regexp
        "\\(.*?\\)"
        "\\(?:[ \t]+:[[:alnum:]:_@#%]+:\\)?[ \t]*$"))
      (match-string 1))
     (no-todo
      (looking-at org-todo-line-regexp)
      (match-string 3))
     (t (looking-at org-heading-regexp)
        (concat
          (match-string 1)
          " "
          (match-string 2)
          (if (and (looking-at lawlist-org-heading-regexp) (match-string 3))
            (match-string 3)) )))))

(defvar lawlist-org-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(.*?\\)\\)?[ \t]*\\(\n.*DEADLINE.*$\\)"
  "Custom match org headline, plus the second line with a deadline.")
```